# Subclass NSTableRowView for NSOutlineView

Tags: macos, nstableview, nsoutlineview

If you have a tableView and want to use a subclass of NSTableRowView, you can use the delegate function - (NSTableRowView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row.  Any ideas of how I can do this with an NSOutlineView (without subclassing NSOutlineView)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The NSOutlineView has this delegate method:

- (NSTableRowView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView rowViewForItem:(id)item

that serves the same purpose for an outline view. I don't see this method in my docs in Xcode, but it's declared in NSOutlineView.h in MacOSX10.7.sdk