# How to change the color of the Selected Row in NSOutlineView

Tags: macos, view, selection, nsoutlineview

I am using **View based `NSOutlineView`**, which was subclassed. The Default Blue color was showing in outline view while selecting the `Outline view`. How to change selection color?.

*Note: I am using view based outlineview, not cell based.*

I found the method for cell based outlineview.

```
-(void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item;
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to subclass [NSTableRowView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableRowView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) then override the method drawSelectionInRect: in your subclass something like this

```
- (void)drawSelectionInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    if (self.selectionHighlightStyle != NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone) {
        NSRect selectionRect = NSInsetRect(self.bounds, 2.5, 2.5);
        [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:.65 alpha:1.0] setStroke];
        [[NSColor redColor] setFill];
        NSBezierPath *selectionPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:selectionRect xRadius:6 yRadius:6];
        [selectionPath fill];
        [selectionPath stroke];
    }
}
```

Then in your NSOutlineView delegate call the following and return your new subclass

```
- (NSTableRowView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView rowViewForItem:(id)item
```

This method doesn't seem to be documented see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771144/subclass-nstablerowview-for-nsoutlineview)

Comment: I was only able to make this work by also overriding the backgroundColor property of NSTableRowView. The color I return doesn't seem to matter, but if I don't override it, the drawSelectionInRect: method is not called.